# Add new field to core module by overide drupal 7

Tags: forms

I want to add one more field of Sex (male/female)radio button in core Login Form Module. How do i achieve this by override.

Comment: My answer for this question is for old topic, where it was asked to add a gender radio at login form.

Comment: @RajeevK I apologize: I edited the question since adding a radio button to select the gender in the login form doesn't make any sense. I will revert the edit, and close the question.

Comment: @Yogesh Welcome to Drupal Answers! With questions about code, you are asked to show the code you are using. This site's purpose is not writing code somebody needs; we can help you change the code you are using, but we don't write code from scratch for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding field into login form is not very difficult. You can do it easily by making a custom module & altering the login form by help of [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) like this.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $options = array(0 => t('Male'), 1 => t('Female'));
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_block' || $form_id == 'user_login') {
    $form['gender'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('Gender'),
      '#options' => $options,
      '#description' => t('Select your gender'),
    );
  }
  return $form;
}
```

But next things will be tricky: for example, what you have to do with their selected values.

Comment: Where should i add this code??
In template.php or i have to create my own module?
Please help me.

Comment: You will have to create a custom module. Read documentation for creating modules - https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7

Comment: And where should I mention this module so drupal will get to know to use this form_alter ?

Is it require to write code to know drupal to use this form alter ?

Comment: you need to add a submit handler to save the value. (sidenote: isn't it possible to add fields to a user with profile module?)

Comment: If Drupal 7, any reason not to suggest using `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` to add this field from the standard UI?

Comment: @Jimajamma Question has been edited. Previously it was for login form & now it's for registration form :)

Comment: $options = array(0 => t('Male'), 1 => t('Female'), 2 => t('Other'));
    if ($form_id == 'search-block-form') {
 $form['gender'] = array(
   '#type' => 'radios',
   '#title' => t('Gender'),
   '#options' => $options,
   '#description' => t('Select your gender'),
 );
    }

Problem with above code. Not showing expected result only for **"search-block-form"**

Comment: @Yogesh Please read FAQs about getting help here - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @Jimajamma I apologize: It was me editing the question to something that made more sense. I reverted the edit, since I cannot help a user who doesn't know the difference between the login form and the registration one with getting the answer he probably needs.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It's ok :)

Comment: Ditto, @kiamlaluno all good, especially with the question creep that had started :)